# JPQL - Calculate difference between Timestamps

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

I want to calculate the difference between the `TIMESTAMP` saved in the Database with the `CURRENT_TIMSTAMP` and verify if the number of **days** between them is less than a given number.

```
TypedQuery<Person> q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE (p.createdOn - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP <= :constant))", Person.class);
```

The `p.createdOn` is automatically set by the Database.

The `constant` would be the number of days the difference has to be less than.

```
q.setParameter("constant", 14);
```

The query is compiling but not retrieving what it needs to and I am unable to get the number of days between them working in my query.

An alternative (inefficient) approach is getting all and looping through them and calculating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to subtract `createdOn` from the current date, not vice versa (otherwise, result is always negative and condition always evaluates to `true`).

Secondly, if date operations don't work as expected, you can always calculate the date limit before query execution and pass it as parameter:

```
Date date = // current date minus three days

TypedQuery<Person> q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.createdOn >= :date", Person.class);
q.setParameter("date", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

JPQL:

```
SELECT p
FROM Person p
WHERE day(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - p.createdOn) <= :constant))
```